# Listening for input in programmatically instantiated xib templates

Tags: ios, uibutton, xib

I am currently messing around with programmatically adding and removing template Views; to remove a UIView template, a user has to tap a button within it.

However, I am not sure how to get the parent view controller to handle button inputs. I would like the parent view controller to know when the button is pressed instead of having the xib class handle that because otherwise I would have to a lot of circling and it would get annoying really fast.

Likewise, I cannot manually connect the button itself to the ViewController class because these xibs are added in during runtime.

How do I get a parent ViewController to handle the UIButton inputs within a custom XIB template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Likewise, I cannot manually connect the button itself to the ViewController class because these xibs are added in during runtime

That's not true, because you can certainly call `addTarget(_:action:for:)` to connect the button action to the view controller target at the time you "add the xib."

However, an even cooler solution would be configure your button in the xib with a nil-targeted action. This means we don't need an explicit target; we simply have to know the name of the method that the action will call. The view controller is higher up the responder chain than the button (once you "add the xib" to view controller's view), and so when the button is tapped, the method will be found dynamically by walking up the responder chain.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the method

```
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(yourMethodName), for: .touchUpInside)
```

here the "button" will be the reference of the button in your xib. "self" will be the reference of the viewController in which you are adding the .xib.